# Continuously add digits to a string

Tags: string, c#-4.0, collections, selenium-webdriver, iteration

Just a quick one, I want to continuously add digits to a string. The first thing I did is to remove the last character of the string, now digits starting from 1 should be continuously added to it. The snippet is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static String source = "#box1";
        static string dest;
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                if (source.Length > 0)
                {
                    dest = source.Substring(0, source.Trim().Length - 1);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(dest);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch(Exception e){ e.ToString(); }
        }
    }
}
```

The output should look like this:

```
#box1
#box2
#box3
#box4
#box5
```

and so on.....

Comment: instead of removing the last digit I recommend you just have source be "#box" right from the start, this way you don't have to ever remove it you just had to append the number. Easily done with a for loop:

`for(int boxNum = 1; i <= numberOfBoxes; i++) Console.WriteLine(source+i);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a max :

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("#Box" + i);
    }
```

With no maximum, but that is not a good idea:

```
count = 1
while (1 > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("#Box" + count);
    count++;
}
```

You can also do no max with the for loop, but I just wanted to give you more options in loops.

Information on loops http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/loops/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys, 
I got it solved this way. Sorry that I have to post the real code I'm using it for. I'm much occupied than to edit the pseudo code again.

```
public static String RegistrationFailedPanels = UserValidations.RegistrationFailedPanels;
            public static String CloseFailedPanel         = UserValidations.CloseFailedPanel;
            static int count = 0;

            public void LoginFailed(String InputConstant, String FailedLogin)
            {
                ++count;
                InputConstant = RegistrationFailedPanels.Substring(0, RegistrationFailedPanels.Trim().Length-1);
                FailedLogin = CloseFailedPanel.Substring(0, CloseFailedPanel.Trim().Length-1);
                new LoginValidations(driver).WaitForATime(InputConstant +count);
                driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(FailedLogin +count)).Click();
            }
```